# .htaccess - mod_dir with RewriteRule Proxy

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I am running into an unusual problem. I have a series of sites that art pointing to my hosted site, for example purposes:

http://sub.mydomain.com/help/

All these other sites use this .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.mydomain.com/$1 [P,E=Proxy-Host:sub.mydomain.com]
```

It is working great for the most part. Let's call one of these other domains "sub.otherdomain.com".

If I go to `http://sub.otherdomain.com/help/` it works fine.

If I go to `http://sub.otherdomain.com/help` it is getting redirected to `http://sub.mydomain.com/help/`

The reason is because [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) is redirecting the / to the main domain.

I want it to redirect the / to the proxied domain.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try `DirectorySlash Off` in your `sub.otherdomain.com` config.

Comment: Doesn't work - the htaccess on sub.mydomain.com (standard wordpress) is the one that is causing the issue. If you put `DirectorySlash Off` there it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set `ProxyPassReverse`. This can't be done in htaccess. You need to add this in the `<VirtualHost>` section.

Comment: VirtualHost of what? httpd.conf? Can you give me an example of what that would look like?

Comment: I meant inside httpd.conf, but it's probably wise to put in into the virtual host that defines otherdomain. Mine is located in `/etc/apache2/site-enabled/<name of host or something>`.